# how to generate and select a dropdown item dynamically using angularjs, php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, html

I have a list of items for a dropdown and I need to generate and select an item which is stored in datatable using angularjs,php and mysql. i already have a code to retrieve items from a datatable and display it in a grid. i need to display the selected item in dropdown with in the grid.

HTML code

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" id="grid" aria-describedby="grid_info" style="width: 1307px;">
 <thead>
   <tr role="row">
     <th class="sorting_disabled" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style=" text-align:center">S.No<a ng-click="sort_by('{{rowRenderIndex+1}}');"></a></th>
           <th class="sorting_disabled">Employee<a ng-click="sort_by('empl_name');"></a></th>
           <th class="sorting_disabled">Work<a ng-click="sort_by('name');"></a></th>
           <th class="sorting_disabled center">Validate<a ng-click="sort_by('status');"></a></th>
           <th class="sorting_disabled center">Work Score<a ng-click="sort_by('task_score');"></i></a></th>
      </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
          <td class="sorting_disabled">{{rowRenderIndex+1}}</td>
          <td class="sorting_disabled">{{data.empl_name}}</td>
          <td class="sorting_disabled">{{data.work}}</td>
          <td class="center"><div align="center">
              <select name="">                  
                 <option>current</option> 
                 <option>Incomplete</option>  
                 <option>completed</option>
                 <option>Validated</option>
              </select></div></td>
         <td class="sorting_disabled">{{data.task_score}}</td>
         <td class="center"><div align="center"><input class="inp" type="text" id="{{data.employee}}" name="{{data.employee}}" onblur="" value="{{data.employee_score}}" /></div></td>
       </tr>
  </table>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
    return [];
   }
});
app.controller('workManagement', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$http.get('workmanagement.php').success(function(data){`enter code here`
    $scope.list = data;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
    $scope.entryLimit = 5; //max no of items to display in a page
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
});


$scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
};
$scope.filter = function() {
    $timeout(function() { 
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
    }, 10);
};
$scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};
```

});

PHP Code

```
 include('config.php');

$con = mysqli_connect(APP_HOST,APP_USERNAME,APP_PASSWORD);
mysqli_select_db($con ,APP_DB);

$query="SELECT * FROM workmanagement";
//$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$result = mysqli_query($con ,$query);

$arr = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
  }
  # JSON-encode the response
  $json_response = json_encode($arr);

  // # Return the response
  echo $json_response;
```

Comment: Please post what you have done for this problem

Comment: Please add some code here to see your problem and also see stackoverflow help how to wirte a good question,
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Guys - while I agree there should almost always be code how can he show code when he does not know how to do it? The only code he would be able to provide given his question relates to pulling the code from mysql/php and displaying it in a table - irrelevant to using angularjs directives to display it in a drop down. His question was very clear.

Comment: @IfTrue The question might be clear, but it still does not show any previous research by the OP.

Comment: From the link the previous person who agreed with you posted "Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some." and nowhere in it does it state you need to provide any previous research. I am happy you guys are trying to encourage quality but I don't think it is applicable here.

Comment: It says right at the top: "Search, and research", as well as in the sidebar when asking a question: "Share your research.". And I'm sure you would agree a quick Google search for "AngularJS dropdown" would easily yield enough results to answer this question.

Comment: @muenchdo I originally posted showing the link does not say to post your research , which is true, but on looking up posting a question you are correct it does state to include it when you are posting so you are correct.

Comment: Thanks to all. I am a beginner. i know something in php and  mysql. i have interest to know angular js. very sorry if my question is wrong or unclear. i will post my code, what i am doing now.

Comment: I have posted the code what i have tried. Pls direct me to the right path.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To populate the items into the drop down you need two things: 1) the ng-model directive and 2) the ng-options directive. Here is an example:

```
<select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="item.name for item in itemList" / >
```

Where itemList stands for $scope.itemList (could be anything you call it really) in your controllers scope. Note that the selector portion of item.name (.name) is dependent on the properties of your items.